# Unix: Bash Script

Tags: unix

I need help formulating a script that will only extract shell comments out of scripts. I cannot use grep, awk or sed in my script. The script will only read from the standard input only lines with shell comments, but not the sh-bang i.e. #! /bin/bash

If the script does not contain any comments. The script will print "No Comments Found" in the standard output.

I done some research online and looked examples in the book, but I do not how or where to start on something like this. It sounds like I have to use an if/else statement, but I am a struggling on formulating this together.

Comment: Why can't you use grep, awk or sed? They seem like ideal tools for this job. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I am doing continuing education to learn the ins and out of Unix and I am working out of a book. The part of the book I am working in is focused on bash scripts only.

Comment: *Usually* bash scripts *are* implemented by using external programs like sed, awk, xargs, etc.

Comment: I understand that, but for this project I cannot use sed, awk, etc. That is why I may have to utilize an if, then, else statement in my bash script to ensure that only # comments are pulled from the script along with the line number the comment is on. If there are no comments in the script, than the standard output will display "No Comments Available". I don't know where to start and I spend hours reading and researching and I still cannot put anything on paper or in the command window.

Comment: You might use `while read -r line; do if [[ "${line}" ...<somescript`. Try and show us something with this.